# Using a Loader in a Fragment causes a NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-loader

I'm using a `android.support.v4.content.Loader` in a `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and sometimes I get a

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.content.Loader.abandon()' on a null object reference

This is my first time using a loader and I'm not 100% sure how they work.
I also want the loader to refresh data every minute, so I'm using a handler and runnable to call `loaderManager.restartLoader()` every minute. (If that's not what you're supposed to do, I'm open to better ideas)

So far I have the `Runnable` as a global variable:

```
private Runnable mStatusChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
            refresh();
    }
};
```

which calls the refresh() function:

```
public void refresh() {
    if (MainActivity.isConnected) {
        loaderManager.restartLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }
}
```

That line of code, loaderManager.restartLoader, sometimes throws the exception (although sometimes it works).

In `OnCreateView` I initialize the loader and the handler

```
   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_for_fragments, container, false);


    loaderManager = getLoaderManager();

    if (MainActivity.isConnected) {
        loaderManager.initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
    }

    adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), exchanges, R.color.colorPrimaryDark);

    listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);


    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Exchange exchange = exchanges.get(i);
            String url = exchange.getUrl();
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(browserIntent);

        }
    });

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    mHandler = new Handler();
    mHandler.postDelayed(mStatusChecker, refreshRate);


    setHasOptionsMenu(true);


    return rootView;
```

and the onCreateLoader method is

```
public Loader onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {

    String[] strings = {QUADRIGA_BTC};

    if (isAdded()){
        return new BLoader(getActivity(), strings);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have 4 very similar fragments that all have a similar loader, and the fragments are managed by a tablayout and viewpager.

Comment: Don't return null from `onCreateLoader()`.

Comment: I've tried changing onCreateLoader() to     `public Loader onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {

        String[] strings = {QUADRIGA_BTC};
            return new BLoader(getActivity(), strings);
    }` but that makes things worse and throws a   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Comment: Do you stop posting that `Runnable` somewhere? Actually, are you sure you need to be doing that in the first place? Where's your date coming from? And what's up with the `MainActivity.isConnected` field?

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured out the issue. Removing callbacks from the `Runnable` in `onStop()` seems to have fixed it. My changes:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mStatusChecker);
}
```